# Understanding azure slots swapping and effect on git repositories

Tags: git, azure, staging, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots

I am trying to create 2 different slots in Azure for a Web application (*staging* and *production*). I am using "Local Git Repository" to push my already built application to Azure (so, no VSTS).

From my tests, I noticed that swapping between the slots also affects the git repositories. I was expecting actually to be fixed.

Is there a way to avoid swapping the repositories? I guess not? I don't understand why Azure decided to swap the git repositories as well.. could anybody explain?

Currently I could only find this flow that seems to somehow work:

I connected my local repository to the *staging* slot and I only push there (*production* is disconnected). When *staging* version is qualified, swap to *production* is performed.

*Note: The flow was broken when *production* was not disconnected!

Could you guys recommend a better approach. Am I seeing it all wrong?

Thanks a lot!